# Chain rule, directional derivative - multivariable calculus

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am having a difficult time to understand the chain rule, and I have this exercise:

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ to be a differentiable function. Define $\psi(x,y)=f(xy,x^2y^2)$. How to compute the partial derivatives and how to proof that the directional derivative $D_{(-x,y)}\psi(x,y)=0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\psi_x=y\cdot f_x+2xy^2\cdot f_y$$
$$\psi_y=x\cdot f_x+2x^2y\cdot f_x$$

and we have

$$D_{(-x,y)}\psi=-x\cdot \psi_x+y\cdot\psi_y=0$$